# Git push, stream message to client terminal

Tags: git

Say I have a git server. On every push, I need to kick off a process, and I can do this via a hook.

The need is to write the process's stdout on to the git client, who did the push. This is much similar to Heroku or Openshift push.

Question is - How do I send text streams/message back to a git client, so that it would print it on the terminal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Git Hook page](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks) does mention:

> Both standard output and standard error output are forwarded to [`git send-pack`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-send-pack) on the other end, so you can simply `echo` messages for the user.

Don't forget to add a `set -x` if you want to see *all* the commands executed by your script.

Answer (score 3):

Although @VonC's answer was perfect for me, I also came across a library that helps in this case.

[Gitreceived](https://github.com/flynn/flynn/tree/master/gitreceived) is a part of the [Flynn](http://flynn.io) project:

> An SSH server made specifically for accepting git pushes that will trigger an auth script and then a receiver script to handle the push.